# NODE Passport HTTP REQUEST

Tags: node.js, http, passport.js

Is it safe to keep user's data into req.user and req.passport? Is it easily accessible and readable for third party from the browser?

I am using req.user to check by ID if mongoose entry belongs to the user from req.user. My concern is that if req.user and req.passport are accessible from the browser then it is easy to manipulate POST request and skip my validations.

Regards,
AA

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using passport with Express, then passport does not make available any user information to the browser.

The way this would normally work is that when a client first contacts your server, a unique encrypted sessionID would be put into a cookie and that's all the browser can ever see.  That sessionID is a key into a server-side store that provides server-side access to user session information.  None of that information is available on the browser side of things unless the server explicitly makes some of that data available by putting it into web pages or exposing endpoints to query it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I understand only session ID is visible in browser and is stored in cookie. So even if I see user ID and username in req.passport and req.user this means that it is only stored on the server side?

Comment: Can anyone change req.passport and req.user data before posting request to my website? For example changing user ID?

Comment: @Tomek - We could answer a lot more specifically if you showed us your code that creates a session and shows how you are using passport.  If you are using them normally as we would expect, then those type of `req` variables are not directly settable by the end-user.  They come from the server-side middleware based on the session cookie.  Questions about your code really should include the relevant ports of your code.

Comment: Ok, it means that passport is storing all data on the server side and is matching client-server based on the session ID stored in the cookie. Right? I attached my code.

Comment: @Tomek - Asking for a general security review is not really on-topic for stack overflow.  In your code, `req.user` will only be available server-side.  That property is created server side, using the session ID and the server-side session store by your middleware and is not available client-side.  Your code has no references to `req.passport` so I don't know what that is.  I believe I've answered the question you originally asked.  If you want to ask an additional specific question, you can write another question, describe the exact question and show the code relevant to that question.